# How to protect bot framework URLS from direct Access

Tags: security, authentication, botframework

We are planning to use Microsoft bot framework to develop a bot for enterprise users once they login to our enterprise website they will be able to see the bot. How do we secure the bot URLS from publicly accessible . 
How can i make sure that only enterprise users with a logged in session will get access to Bot.

Went through some of the documentation Microsoft provided like the token mechanism through direct line channel but still i am not convened. Any one have a reference architecture diagram for the same ? Or have you ever implemented such solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean your bot app's endpoint specifically (e.g. `/api/messages`)?

When you're using the Azure Bot Service (ABS) that is proxying all incoming traffic via one of the many channels it supports. The bot app itself is then receiving incoming requests, in the form of normalized activities, via the ABS Connector protocol. This communication is secured via HTTPS and authenticated by JWT tokens which are signed and verifiable.

Now, when using the Bot Builder SDK (BBSDK), the BBSDK will validate the incoming JWT token to make sure it's properly signed. It does this by getting the public key from a metadata document which it knows comes from a valid (DNS/SSL'd) host name and then validates the signature with the public key. This way it knows the incoming request is indeed from ABS and can trust it.